# How to pass an array of integers to a method expecting `Array<T>`?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, kotlin

I have converted [java shellSort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833423/shell-sort-java-example) to Kotlin. The problem is I have no idea to call this method.

Java

```
package Sorts;
public class ShellSort extends Sorter{

@Override
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    int h = 1;
    while((h*3+1) < a.length)
        h = 3*h+1;
    while(h > 0){
        for(int i = h-1; i < a.length; i++){
            T s = a[i];
            int j = i;
            for(j = i; (j>=h) && (a[j-h].compareTo(s) > 0); j-=h)
                a[j] = a[j-h];
            a[j] = s;
        }
        h /= 3;
    }
}
}
```

Kotlin

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> shellSort(a: Array<T>) {
    var h = 1
    while (h * 3 + 1 < a.size)
        h = 3 * h + 1
    while (h > 0) {
        for (i in h - 1..a.size - 1) {
            val s = a[i]
            var j = i
            j = i
            while (j >= h && a[j - h].compareTo(s) > 0) {
                a[j] = a[j - h]
                j -= h
            }
            a[j] = s
        }
        h /= 3
    }
}
```

What I have tried to call is cast intArray to array

```
 val array = intArrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4)
 shellSort(arrayOf(array))
```

Which comes with error

[image]

```
Type parameter bound for T in 

 fun <T : Comparable<T>> shellSort(a: Array<T>) : Unit

is not satisfied: inferred type IntArray is not a subtype of Comparable<IntArray>
```

Comment: By calling `arrayOf(array)` you create a 2D array of type `Array<IntArray>`, this is why you get the error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`intArrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/int-array-of.html) returns `IntArray` which **does not extend** `Array<Int>` as one might assume. As [stated in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html) Kotlin provides specialized array types for various primitives that avoid boxing overhead. `IntArray` corresponds to Java's `int[]`. The `ShellSort.sort` method (both Kotlin and Java) requires boxed versions.

You can convert `IntArray` to `Array<Int>` using [`toTypedArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) extension method like so:

```
val array = intArrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4).toTypedArray()
shellSort(array)
```

Or as @KirillRakhman suggested create a boxed version directly:

```
shellSort(arrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4))
```

Comment: You can also create a boxed array directly using `arrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4)`

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
shellSort(arrayOf(array))
```

does not cast `IntArray array` to a regular `Array<Integer>`, but wraps it in a singleton array of type `Array<IntArray>`. Use `IntArray.toTypedArray()` to convert it to a generic array, as `@miensol` suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but "IntArray.toTypedArray()" may work with Java but not for Kotlin